# GUI calculator returns 0

Tags: java

When I run my code for the first round (mult.), it works, but if I try again, putting in "answer" for the first prompt, it gives me 0. Why?

```
package gui.calc;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GUICalc {
    public static double mult(double mult1, double mult2) {
        mult1 *= mult2;
        return mult1;
    }

    public static double div(double div1, double div2) {
        div1 /= div2;
        return div1;
    }

    public static double add(double add1, double add2) {
        add1 += add2;
        return add1;
    }

    public static double sub(double sub1, double sub2) {
        sub1 -= sub2;
        return sub1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean goAgain = true;
        double finalAns = 1;
        while (goAgain == true) {

            Object[] options = { "*", "/", "+", "-" };
            int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                    "Choose your                              operationr",
                    "this is null", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
            String s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter nums",
                    "Enter NUm", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            String s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter nums",
                    "Enter NUm", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            double d1 = 0;
            double d2 = 0;
            if (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("answer")) {
                d1 = finalAns;
            }

            else if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase("answer")) {
                d2 = finalAns;
            } else {
                d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
                d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
            }
            if (n == 0) {
                double mult1 = mult(d1, d2);
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, mult1, "dsfa",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                finalAns = mult1;
            } else if (n == 1) {
                double div1 = div(d1, d2);
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, div1, "dsfa",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                finalAns = div1;
            } else if (n == 2) {
                double plus1 = add(d1, d2);
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, plus1, "dsfa",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                finalAns = plus1;
            } else if (n == 3) {
                double sub1 = sub(d1, d2);
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, sub1, "dsfa",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                finalAns = sub1;
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, finalAns, "hi",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "GO AGAIN?", "daf",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                goAgain = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn to use debugger.

Comment: I have a debugger, I think. I am using netbeans. What is the problem with it though?

Comment: It's for you to find out and debugger will help you to go step-by-step executing your code and inspecting values of your variables.

Comment: How do I do that in NetBeans? (Sorry I'm clueless)

Comment: I did run the debugger in netbeans, but it didn't give me anything

Comment: What debugger gives you is an opportunity to look at you code execution *from inside*.  It's a tool not a magic wand.  See if this tutorial helps:  https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/debug-visual.html (I'm an Eclipse person so I have no first hand experience with NetBeans.)

Comment: Start by using Google to search for something like: how to use netbeans debugger.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReLlcbi1es4

Comment: Look at your code and think about this: if you enter `answer` for the first argument, what ends up in `d1`, and what ends up in `d2`? The `d2` part is the part where you should focus.

Comment: I get these types of errors now & then. Note: just bec. something runs the *first* time doesn't mean it'll keep running. In fact, you can divide a code-segment/func'y into 3 parts - 1. beginning .. 2. middle. 3. end

Comment: I think you're *real* close , anyhow. carefully follow DaoWen's advice. he's probably hot here

Comment: @DaoWen Like I said before, I'm absolutely clueless. I assume (undoubtedly wrongly) that if d1's argument is "answer", then d2's should be parseDouble of s2. So where is my mistake?

Comment: @Adel Like I said before, I'm absolutely clueless. I assume (undoubtedly wrongly) that if d1's argument is "answer", then d2's should be parseDouble of s2. So where is my mistake?

Comment: Yeah I tried to run code but i dont have eclipse on this machine. U may benefit from putting in print statements at various spots, just to check the argument values. Si even tho you are using GUI, you can read println statemnts on console. it helps I thnk. ok goodluck

Answer (score 1):

This is where the problem is at:

```
        double d1 = 0;
        double d2 = 0;
        if (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("answer")) {
            d1 = finalAns;
        }

        else if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase("answer")) {
            d2 = finalAns;
        } else {
            d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
            d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
        }
```

If `s1` is *answer*, then the first `if` block will be executed. That will set `d1 = finalAns`, but `d2` is just going to be `0` because that's what it was initialized to, and it never gets assigned anything else. This is what I think you meant to do:

```
        double d1 = 0;
        double d2 = 0;
        if (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("answer")) {
            d1 = finalAns;
        } else {
            d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
        }

        if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase("answer")) {
            d2 = finalAns;
        } else {
            d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
        }
```